# mysql stored proc is not working from mysqlworkbench or java code

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have written a stored proc in mysql when i am running it through hopper it is working fine but when i am trying to run it from mysql workbench or java it is not returning any result and also not showing any exception

I will request you to please help me on this

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `issueitem`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE inventoryids INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE batch varchar(39);
  DECLARE resultstr varchar(3000) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE exp DATE;
  DECLARE mfgdate DATE;
  DECLARE availableunit INT;
  DECLARE quantity INT DEFAULT 100; 
  DECLARE oldest_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE cur_count INT;
  DECLARE que_size INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT inventoryid,batch,exp,availableunit FROM aashramdata.inventory where itemid=1 ORDER BY exp ASC;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN curs;
    SET cur_count=quantity;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curs INTO inventoryids,batch,exp,availableunit;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET que_size = que_size + availableunit;
        IF cur_count >= availableunit THEN
    set cur_count=cur_count-availableunit;
        set resultstr=CONCAT(resultstr,batch,' - ',exp,' - ',availableunit,' - ');  
    update aashramdata.inventory set  `availableunit`=0 where inventoryid=inventoryids;
    END IF;
    IF cur_count < availableunit THEN

    update aashramdata.inventory set  `availableunit`=availableunit-cur_count where inventoryid=inventoryids;
        set resultstr=CONCAT(resultstr,batch,' - ',exp,' - ',availableunit-cur_count,' - ');

    set cur_count=0;
    END IF;
    IF que_size >= quantity then
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE curs;
  select resultstr;
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the procedure is apparently syntactically valid, it's impossible to answer what the problem might be, without some knowledge of the data.

The easiest way to debug a stored procedure is by peppering it with unbounded `SELECT` statements (that is, selects that are not part of a subquery and not part of an `INSERT ... SELECT` or `SELECT ... INTO`) and then running it from the MySQL command line client, which handles multiple result sets from stored procedures much more gracefully than most graphical clients.

For example:

```
...
SET cur_count=quantity;
SELECT cur_count;                                       -- add this 
read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH curs INTO inventoryids,batch,exp,availableunit;
  SELECT inventoryids,batch,exp,availableunit;          -- add this
  SELECT done;                                          -- add this
  IF done THEN
...
```

When run from the command line client...

```
mysql> CALL issueitem();
```

...output will start rolling out of the console at you, showing you the internal values the procedure is encountering as it iterates the loop.

This, or other `SELECT` statements like this added elsewhere, will expose the internal variables and this should help you find the problem.  You'll need to remove them before you call the procedure from code or even the GUI since the GUI may not handle them well -- it may start opening new tabs or splitting panes or just ignoring everything after the first `SELECT`.

Note that the last iteration of the loop, you may see the values from the previous iteration repeated since the failed read from the cursor may not reset the variables, but "done" will also transition from 0 to 1 indicating that the cursor has run out of rows and fired the `CONTINUE HANDLER`, so those values won't actually have been processed twice.